# Google Place API - how to extract the LRD code

Tags: google-places-api

So LRD(eg.0x88f50e9776ef46b5:0xf65caab6fccd3bdf) is a pointer to google review window. Is there a way to extract that code using Google Place API?

Comment: Working on this myself.  So far I've discovered the second half of that hex code is the hex equivalent of the CID, which can be found via the api and some parsing.  Haven't figured out what the first half is yet.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out a way to extract the LRD code from the google maps page of a business. See the php code below.
The place ID of a business can be easily retrieved using Google Place API.

```
<?
     $contents = file_get_contents("https://maps.google.com/?cid=".$_POST['place_id']);

    preg_match("/(0x[a-z0-9]{4,}:0x[a-z0-9]{4,})/",$contents,$matches);

    echo $matches[0]; //LRD code
?>
```